# How to display uploaded image with php laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, phpmyadmin

How can I display uploaded image from stored location and I want to carry over the same image name to

```
<input id = "Picture" type="file" name="Picture" accept="image/*" />
```

This code is used in `Controller.php` when upload

```
$img = $input['Picture'];
$name = $img->getClientOriginalName();
$uploaded = $img->move('public/img', $name);
```

This is where uploaded image will show in my `new.blade.php`

```
<img src="#" id="Image" name="Image" />
```

And Image name doesn't save original name to mysql, it saved like `C:xampp mpphpB7CF.tmp`

How can I do to save original name that I Uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code this is working code.

```
$file = $request->file('Picture');
$destinationPath = 'public/img/';
$originalFile = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->move($destinationPath, $originalFile);
```

This line `$originalFile = $file->getClientOriginalName();` will assign original file name to  `$originalFile` and use this variable name where you insert image in database.

Add below line to display image you have uploaded.

`<img src='{{ asset('img/'.$originalFile) }}'>`

Comment: Sorry!! Saved name is still not original name. I used phpMyAdmin

Comment: Here is my working code please check; 
`       $file = $request->file('Picture');
        $destinationPath = 'public/img/';
        $originalFile = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($destinationPath, $originalFile);
        $productImage = \App\ProductImage::find(4);
        $productImage->product_image = $originalFile;
        $productImage->update();`

Comment: How to image that is uploaded in public folder?

Answer (score 2):

```
$path = '';

if ($request->hasFile('Picture')) {
    $file = $request->file('Picture');
    $path = $file->storeAs(public_path('img'), $imageName);

    //or
    if (file_put_contents(public_path(img) . $imageName, $file)) {
        $path = public_path(img) . $imageName;
    }
}

return view('your-view', ['img_path' => $path]);;
```

and in your `new.blade.php`

```
<img src="{{ $img_path }}" id="Image" name="Image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In Controller

```
public function show($name)
{
    $extension = File::extension($name);
        $path = public_path('storage/' . $name);
        if (!File::exists($path)) {abort(404);}
        $file = File::get($path);
        $type = File::mimeType($path);
        $response = Response::make($file, 200);
        $response->header("Content-Type", $type);
        return $response;
```

}

Route

```
Route::get('/images/{name}', 'FileController@show');
```

Index.blade.php

```
<a href='{{ asset("images/$hire_details->file") }}'>click here to view image</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Return your $uploaded from controller to view

```
return view('new',['uploaded'=>$uploaded]);
```

and then in your view

```
<img src='{{ asset($uploaded) }}' >
```

Comment: Thank!! But I have a <img> tag in my new.blade. I want to display in it.

Comment: Return your view from your controller and then display in it

Answer (score 0):

Return path from controller and display :

```
<img src='{{ asset('img/'.$name) }}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
use Input;
use Image;

$file = Input::file('Picture');
$imageName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

$imgUpload = Image::make($file)->save(public_path('img/' . $imageName));

<img src="{{ asset('img/'.$imageName) }}">
```

Note: If you have get error for `Image` then install package for `Image` from this [link](https://packagist.org/packages/intervention/image)